# installing ruby 1.9.2 for octopress

Tags: ruby

So, I am trying to install [Octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/). I need ruby 1.9.2. It looks like `sudo apt-get install ruby` wants to install ruby 1.8. I've read that [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is a good way to go. But it seems rather excessive since I don't expect to use much else apart from the bare-bones needed for octopress. Do I have an alternative?

I use a TeXlive 2011 I installed myself, but I like being up to date there. For ruby, I literally only want it for Octopress, so I don't really want to have to deal with maintenance separately if I can avoid it. I'd prefer if `sudo apt-get update` would deal with it for me.

I know there are PPAs. But the thing is, there are *loads* of PPAs. How do I choose a trustworthy one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*note that I'm writing this on Ubuntu 12.04, however this should work on 11.10*
Open a terminal, then install the `ruby1.9.1-full`, `rake` and `git` packages.

> sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full git rake

Install the `bundler` gem with

> sudo gem install bundler

Then, download a copy of octopress.

> git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git octopress

cd into the octopress directory, and then run

> bundle install

You might need to enter in your password so you can install the gems, as shown here:

> $ bundle install
>
> Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
>
> Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:

Then, just follow the instructions on the [octopress docs](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/) and you should be set! Enjoy octopress!

Note that where you would normally type "rake", you'll need to type `rake1.9.1` instead. I'll update this once I figure out a way around it.

Comment: Can't you just alias `rake` to `rake1.9.1`?

Comment: Well, I know there is a better way to do it system-wide, I just can't remember.

Comment: I needed the following line in my `.zshrc` to get this to work: `alias rake='noglob rake1.9.1'`

Comment: @Seamus Fair enough, that works.

Answer (score 5):

> But the thing is, there are loads of PPAs. How do I choose a
>   trustworthy one?

I'd go with https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-ruby (no 1.9.2 though)

However, this guy seems trustworthy enough (being that he at least documented the ppa in a blog post). It seems there's a "catch" where you have to link the /usr/bin/ruby yourself using update-alternatives:

- http://www.humbug.in/2010/launchpad-ppa-for-ruby-1-9-2-and-some-ruby-bindings/
- http://www.humbug.in/2010/ppa-updates-for-ruby-1-9-1-and-ruby-1-9-2-handling-ruby-versions-using-the-update-alternatives-system/

> I'd prefer if sudo apt-get update would deal with it for me.I'd prefer
>   if sudo apt-get update would deal with it for me.

Usually someone is behind that apt-get update, doing all sorts of tests before releasing it. You can't expect someone to always do the work for you. You could learn [how to create an ubuntu/debian package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) and join the ruby packaging team: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-ruby (..or even create your own team!).

On the other hand, you can always send a message to the team and request ruby 1.9.2.

Finally there's always good-old-not-recommended `checkinstall` if you compile ruby. checkinstall will create the .deb package for you (use it instead of "make install").

> I've read that RVM is a good way to go.

That's what I've been reading so far. I would suggest using rvm, you seem an experienced user.
As far as I can see, using rvm you can upgrade to the latest stable version quite easily: https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/

> To upgrade to the most stable version:
>
> ```
> rvm get stable
> ```
>
> To upgrade to the most recent release version:
>
> ```
> rvm get latest
> ```

Lastly, it seems that rvm is installed in user directory ~/.rvm/ - unless you use `sudo` (which will probably install it in `/usr/local/rvm`): https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/

You can remove it. Uninstall rvm also seems easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/howto-uninstall-rvm

```
rvm implode
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Hope this helps. :)